# Approve/Reject list items SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, approval-process

Can anyone advise me how I can create simple Approve/Reject process for adding items to a list.  I tried the standard Approve/Reject within SharePoint but as the items in my list are regularly updated/reviewed this process doesn't work for me as the items back to Pending.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple designer workflow that will change the status of the item to Approve/Reject manually. Set the workflow to start on Item Creation and Item Modification.

Or you create an automatic approval process by creating a approval workflow. Try below link for more help.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579#__toc264526221

Answer (score 0):

You can use the out-of-the-box approval workflow. All you have to do is associate it to your list. There's a checkbox for "End workflow on change" which you'll just need to leave unchecked. You can set the default people the workflow goes to, and you can give the users the ability to change those names, or not.